# How Can You Calculate Multiple Textboxes?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, calculator

I need help with my program in Visual Studio C#. The user must be able to enter a value into the four blank textboxes. The numbers in the textboxes should multiply with their set prices when the user clicks on Calculate. In other words, I want the four textboxes to multiply with their price.

The Form

[image: Form]

Here's the calculation code. I managed to get the Children 5-12 textbox to calculate.

```
private void btnCalculate_Click (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int FirstTextBoxNumber;
    int SecondTextBoxNumber;
    int answer; 

    try
    {
        Convert.ToInt32(tbSecondNumber.Text);
        FirstTextBoxNumber = int.Parse("2");
        SecondTextBoxNumber = int.Parse(tbSecondNumber.Text);

        answer = FirstTextBoxNumber * SecondTextBoxNumber;

        MessageBox.Show("Your total is £" + answer.ToString());
    }
    catch (FormatException)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a decimal value");
    }
}
```

How the form calculates

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Then what is your problem?

Comment: I'm having trouble trying to calculate all the textboxes together

Comment: replace the answer = portion with whatever calculation you want to do (e.g. what you did for the first and second boxes)

Comment: Why? you just get `FourthTextBoxNumber`, multiple by 3, `SixthTextBoxNumber` multiple by 4, `EighthTextBoxNumber` multiple by 4 then sum all to your answer...

Comment: I tried to do it myself, but I'm not very good at coding

Comment: @ConorCoyle the best way to improve is to mess up a lot

Comment: Can the user change the price? Or does the user only enter in the quantity?

Comment: They can't change the price, grayed out

Comment: How is the `Price` retrieved? Are they hardcoded? If so, you can just multiply in the code without having to retrieve the `Price` in the code behind. ex. `SecondTextboxNumber = SecondTextboxNumber * 2;`. Of course, you should validate that the value entered in the text box is an integer.

Comment: @EricS magic numbers are bad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following inside your `btnCalculate_Click` code:

```
        bool isNumeric = true;
        double answer = 0; 
        double firstTextBoxNumber = 0;
        double thirdTextBoxNumber = 0;
        double fifthTextBoxNumber = 0;
        double seventhTextBoxNumber = 0;

        int secondTextBoxNumber = 0;
        int fourthTextBoxNumber = 0;
        int sixTextBoxNumber = 0;
        int eightTextBoxNumber = 0;

        try
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(tbFirstNumber.Text) || String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(tbSecondNumber.Text) || String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(tbThirdNumber.Text) || String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(tbFourthNumber.Text) || String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(tbFifthNumber.Text) || String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(tbSixNumber.Text) || String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(tbSeventhNumber.Text) || String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(tbEightNumber.Text))
            {
                isNumeric = false;
            }
            else
            {
                //Check if "Prices" are all Doubles
                if (isNumeric)
                {
                    isNumeric = double.TryParse(tbFirstNumber.Text.Replace("£", ""), out firstTextBoxNumber);
                }
                if (isNumeric)
                {
                    isNumeric = double.TryParse(tbThirdNumber.Text.Replace("£", ""), out thirdTextBoxNumber);
                }
                if (isNumeric)
                {
                    isNumeric = double.TryParse(tbFifthNumber.Text.Replace("£", ""), out fifthTextBoxNumber);
                }
                if (isNumeric)
                {
                    isNumeric = double.TryParse(tbSeventhNumber.Text.Replace("£", ""), out seventhTextBoxNumber);
                }

                //Check if "Qty" are all Integers
                if (isNumeric)
                {
                    isNumeric = int.TryParse(tbSecondNumber.Text, out secondTextBoxNumber);
                }
                if (isNumeric)
                {
                    isNumeric = int.TryParse(tbFourthNumber.Text, out fourthTextBoxNumber);
                }
                if (isNumeric)
                {
                    isNumeric = int.TryParse(tbSixNumber.Text, out sixTextBoxNumber);
                }
                if (isNumeric)
                {
                    isNumeric = int.TryParse(tbEightNumber.Text, out eightTextBoxNumber);
                }
            }

            if (isNumeric)
            {
                answer = firstTextBoxNumber * secondTextBoxNumber;
                answer += thirdTextBoxNumber * fourthTextBoxNumber;
                answer += fifthTextBoxNumber * sixTextBoxNumber;
                answer += seventhTextBoxNumber * eightTextBoxNumber;

                MessageBox.Show("Your total is £" + answer.ToString());
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter a decimal value");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
```

The `Try Catch` block was changed because you should only handle system errors in `Try` blocks.

Please do note, I made the following assumptions:

- The price can change, and can be changed to include cents and fractions of cents.
- The price will only remove "£" and no other currency logos.
- The Qty will always be an `int` since you can't have 1.5 children.
- You are ok with the system error being shown in a message box to the
  user instead of being logged somewhere.

Since this was quick, the code could be expanded on to remove some of the assumptions and to add rounding.

Answer (score -1):

OK. I'm going to try to explain it to you:

You have 8 textboxes in your form.
They all have an identifier like textBox1, textBox2 etc..

What you want to take textBox1 and multiply it by textBox2. And this the same for the other 3 pairs. Then add up the total and display it in a messageBox.

I'll try to send you the right way:

```
private void btnCalculate_Click (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int FirstPrice, SecondPrice, ThirdPrice, FourthPrice;
    int FirstQnty, SecondQnty, ThirdQnty, FourthQnty;
    int answer = 0; 

    try
    {
        FirstPrice = (int)TextBox1.Text.Replace("£", "");
        SecondPrice = (int)TextBox2.Text;
        ThirdPrice = (int)TextBox3.Text.Replace("£", "");
        FourthPrice = (int)TextBox4.Text;
        FirstQty = (int)TextBox5.Text.Replace("£", "");
        SecondQty = (int)TextBox6.Text;
        ThirdQty = (int)TextBox7.Text.Replace("£", "");
        FourthQty = (int)TextBox8.Text;

        answer = FirstPrice * FirstQty;
        answer += SecondPrice * SecondQty;
        answer += ThirdPrice * ThirdQty;
        answer += FourthPrice * FourthQty;

        MessageBox.Show("Your total is £" + answer.ToString());
    }
    catch (FormatException)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a decimal value");
    }
    }
```

It might contain some spelling errors, but it should work.
Just replace the TextBox identifiers to the ones in your form.

Comment: What happens if £ is in the Text value for the odd numbered boxes.

Comment: Then we trim it. I'll include it in the code. Good point Marshall

Comment: something else to consider is that you cannot ensure what the user enters into the text boxes is a numeric.

Comment: I'm changing the textbox identifiers to my own, but I get the error cannot convert type 'string' to 'int'